# GCP - How to snapshot all instance that has the label backup=true

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I need to create a snapshot solution that has to consider all vms with the label backup=true.
Based on this documentation (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/scheduled-snapshots?authuser=1&_ga=2.245954500.-1373944797.1588160130&_gac=1.16577604.1588343671.Cj0KCQjwka_1BRCPARIsAMlUmEoYnSJSeng1igXd_3VjMETyKBRvrx-BPyJXNzL1bStf48DSpo2OICQaAkytEALw_wcB), I don't think that is possible to configure it straight from console. I'm considering to create a cloud function in python for implement this solution and create a job in cloud scheduler for call it, what you guys think, any tips or others ideas, thank you in advance?

Comment: You can also use Cloud Workflow because you will perform only API calls: list the VM with the label, iterate on the result and call the snapshot API for each disk. No code, serverless. Cheaper and more scalable. It's my recommendation.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere - Have you written an article on Workflow?

Comment: I have written 2 articles, a third one has been submitted today. But none covers exactly your use case, it's just in the principle, it's the best way IMO to achieve your use case.